# Why am I getting this error? r1= buf1.compare(buf2); ^ TypeError: Object Rahul has no method 'compare'

Tags: node.js, monodevelop

```
/*This a demo program to campare buffers to each other. The expected output should be some numbers so that we came to know that these are equal or not.
taking three buffer variables and storing some data into it.
*/

var buf1 = new Buffer('Rahul');  Buffer contains Rahul
var buf2 = new Buffer('Kumar');  Buffer contains Kumar
var buf3 = new Buffer('Rahul');  Buffer contains Rahul

//now comparing these buffers to each other

r1= buf1.compare(buf2); 
r2= buf1.compare(buf3); 
r3= buf2.compare(buf3);  

//Printing them to console

console.log(r1+ " " + r2 + " " + r3);
```

Comment: The error says "Object Rahul..." i can't see any variable named Rahul here. Only buf1, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'compare' is not a prototype function.
It should be used as:

```
Buffer.compare(b1,b2)
```

Added code example:

```
var b1=new Buffer("a");
var b2=new Buffer("b");
var r=Buffer.compare(b1,b2);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Class Method: Buffer.compare(buf1, buf2)#

    buf1 Buffer
    buf2 Buffer

The same as buf1.compare(buf2). Useful for sorting an Array of Buffers:

var arr = [Buffer('1234'), Buffer('0123')];
arr.sort(Buffer.compare);


https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_compare_buf1_buf2

Comment: That sounds weird. I just added a code section to my answer, could you please try it *exactly* as it is, and tell what exact error you're getting? It works fine for me...

Comment: Buffer.compare(b1,b2)
       ^
TypeError: Object function Buffer(subject, encoding, offset) {
 {some code}

  SlowBuffer.makeFastBuffer(this.parent, this, this.offset, this.length);
} has no method 'compare'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ritzylab1/Documents/Untitled Folder 2/bufCompare.js:13:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3

Comment: It really did work for me... I can only assume an node.js version issue. Mine is  0.12.1,  what is yours?

Comment: just in case, it's extracted by:    >node --version

Comment: from looking at their docs, it seems to have been added in 0.12. See for example the "0.10" docs that don't include such a function: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.8/api/buffer.html  as opposed to 0.12 that includes it: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.0/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Buffer.compare` method was introduced in node 0.12. For e.g. 0.10 one may convert buffers to arrays or to strings and compare them.

Easy (not really efficient) way to check `Buffer` equality is to just convert Buffers to strings with `JSON.stringify(b1)` and do string comparison.

Harder/faster and correct way would be to actually write compare function, which checks buffers equality byte by byte and returns correct `-1`, `0` or `1` as result (needed for sort).