# Does Buffer have a compare method?

Tags: node.js

I am reading NodeJS tutorial and I have reached to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm) page.

There is an example code for the compare method of Buffer objects:

```
var buffer1 = new Buffer('ABC');
var buffer2 = new Buffer('ABCD');
var result = buffer1.compare(buffer2);

if(result < 0) {
   console.log(buffer1 +" comes before " + buffer2);
}else if(result == 0){
   console.log(buffer1 +" is same as " + buffer2);
}else {
   console.log(buffer1 +" comes after " + buffer2);
}
```

which throws this:

> Executing the program.... $node main.js
>
> /web/com/1460883529_55644/main.js:3 var result =
>   buffer1.compare(buffer2);
>
> ^ TypeError: Object ABC has no method 'compare'      at Object. (/web/com/1460883529_55644/main.js:3:22)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>
> at startup (node.js:119:16)
>
> at node.js:929:3

It is strange that in the trace the object is called `ABC` and not `buffer1` and that there is no `compare` method according to the trace. The example which tried to clarify the `compare` method confused me. Can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: whats your node version?

Comment: I am running the code through the server of the tutorial specified in the question (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm)

Comment: It is running Node v0.10.32

Comment: yeah, that method isn't available until 0.12

Comment: I see, so the mistake done in the tutorial was using a method which did not exist in the version they use. Can you post this as an answer along with the place where version which added a given method can be found? I will accept later, as now I have to go :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this error? r1= buf1.compare(buf2); ^ TypeError: Object Rahul has no method 'compare'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910825/why-am-i-getting-this-error-r1-buf1-comparebuf2-typeerror-object-rahul-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial site uses Node v0.10 which is very old and does not even support the methods used in the tutorial itself!

The code works fine in the current release of Node, v4.4.3, as well as any other recent release.  The relevant documentation for `compare()` is here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_compare_otherbuffer

As an aside, you may want to stop using `new Buffer()` in favor of the more recent [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_str_encoding) API.  This is said to improve code safety.

Comment: I am running the code through the tutorial here: Node v0.10.32 and if you click on try it, you will see that Node v0.10.32 is used and the error is experienced. Since this is evidently not the intention of the tutorial, hence my question.

Comment: @LajosArpad: It looks like you're using a very old version of Node.  But I don't see any clickable link in your comment.  I suggest updating to a current version of Node.

Comment: John, I assumed you have seen the link in my question (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm). I am running the code through a Tutorial website, in fact I am reading about NodeJS before actually deciding whether it is worth to work with it. Since the tutorial is using that version, I was curious really how could they put there an example which does not work. Hassansin told me that the method was added at version 0.12, which means that they blundered the version. So the real answer to my question is: they are mistakenly using an older version in the tutorial than needed.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Understood.  I've updated my answer to add a sentence about how that tutorial site is simply broken.  I guess you can't rely on the "Try It" buttons on that site unless they update their Node version.